# Differentiate between a user changing the Checkbox.Checked value, or it programmatically changing

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I see that Checkboxes have a CheckedChanged event. is it possible to tell whether it was changed programmatically, or by the user actually checking the checkbox?

I've got a large grid where the user can type in a filter, or use checkboxes for a sort of "Quick filter" that offers common filtering parameters. Then say they go and modify the filter through the textbox, I was checking whether or not I should programmatically (un)check the CheckBox controls so that it reflects the filter in the textbox.

```
    private void genericCheckbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateFilter();
    }

    private void UpdateFilter()
    {
        if (gdcSVNDefaultView.RowCount == 0)
            return;

        gdcSVNDefaultView.ActiveFilterString = BuildTableFilter();
        gdcSVNDefaultView.BestFitColumns();
    }

    private void gdcSVNDefaultView_ColumnFilterChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblTotalFileCount.Text = gdcSVNDefaultView.RowCount.ToString();

        if (gdcSVNDefaultView.ActiveFilterString.Contains("Normal"))
            cheNormalFiles.Checked = true;
        else
            cheNormalFiles.Checked = false;

        if (gdcSVNDefaultView.ActiveFilterString.Contains("bin") || 
            gdcSVNDefaultView.ActiveFilterString.Contains("obj"))
            cheBinObjFolders.Checked = true;
        else
            cheBinObjFolders.Checked = false;
    }
```

With some very light testing, this seems to work just as I want it to. But I'm afraid that there's some sort of 'infinite loop' case where the ColumnFilterChanged event will fire because of the UpdateFilter method being called when the CheckedChanged event happens, which could in turn cause CheckedChange to happen again since the ColumnFilterChanged manipulates the Checkboxes.

Answer (score 12):

I'd probably detach and then reattach the handler, e.g.

```
private void gdcSVNDefaultView_ColumnFilterChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cheNormalFiles.CheckedChanged -= genericCheckbox_CheckedChanged;
    cheBinObjFolders.CheckedChanged -= genericCheckbox_CheckedChanged;

    // do stuff...

    cheNormalFiles.CheckedChanged += genericCheckbox_CheckedChanged;
    cheBinObjFolders.CheckedChanged += genericCheckbox_CheckedChanged;
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks. While King King's answer is a little shorter, I think my boss my approve of this one more.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Using `flag` for this purpose is OK:

```
bool suppressCheckedChanged;
private void gdcSVNDefaultView_ColumnFilterChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   suppressCheckedChanged = true;
   //.... your own code
   //....
   suppressCheckedChanged = false;
}
private void genericCheckbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(suppressCheckedChanged) return;
    UpdateFilter();
}
```

### UPDATE

Using `flag` is the best way (the most concise and convenient) I think. However, after some searching on the **internal implementation of CheckBox.cs**, I've found that the internal field **checkState** is used. the `Checked` property is designed just for convenience. The `CheckedChanged` event is raised in the setter of the `CheckState` property. So by modifying the `checkState` field, we bypass the `CheckedChanged` event raiser. Because the field `checkState` is not public, we have to use `Reflection` to change its value. That's why this code is a little lengthy compared to using `flag`. 
This is the code for you, note that this is just a reference to open wide the knowledge on this problem, as I said using `flag` is much more concise and the code is also coherent:

```
//Use this extension method for convenience
public static class CheckBoxExtension {
  public static void SetChecked(this CheckBox chBox, bool check){
    typeof(CheckBox).GetField("checkState", BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                            BindingFlags.Instance)
                    .SetValue(chBox, check ? CheckState.Checked : 
                                             CheckState.Unchecked);
    chBox.Invalidate();
  }
}
//then you can use the SetChecked method like this:
checkBox1.SetChecked(true);//instead of checkBox1.Checked = true;
checkBox1.SetChecked(false);//instead of checkBox1.Checked = false;
```

Comment: Hmm, the thought had occurred to me but it seemed too simple. Thanks.

Comment: Haha, I don't know. It's one of those things where it just seems too obvious and easy that I couldn't help but think it wasn't the right / best way. Maybe I just tend to over complicate things?

Comment: @sab669 using `flag` is not some kind of work-around, it's a technique used **frequently** in programming, it's a `straight way`. The point is when you programmatically change the value (`Checked`), if you want to notify that that change should not consequently trigger other code elsewhere, you can explicitly mark some flag for that and other code will use the flag as a **condition** to execute. Another approach is to **detect the actual change by user**, the `Checked` is changed by user via `Click` and `DoubleClick`, so you can handle those events instead of `CheckedChanged`

Comment: It appears that since this was answered the `CheckState` method has been made public, meaning it's as easy to use as the `Checked` method, but won't raise the `CheckedChanged` event.

Answer (score 10):

In general you may use the **Click event** CheckBoxName_Click which is called only when the user click the checkbox (and not when you set the checkbox checked property from code), as the event name suggests.

Comment: This worked really well!  All of the other answers are way more complicated.  Thank you!

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Two different functions for two different ways of changing the state of the checkbox.

Comment: x_CheckChanged is also fired at form loading while _Click is not.

Comment: This responds to mouse click and to spacebar. Exciting!

Answer (score 2):

A bit of a dead thread, but I recently had to solve this and I leveraged the `Focused` property on the checkbox to glean whether or not a user pressed it or if it was triggered programmatically.

I believe all that would need to happen for your use case is wrapping the `UpdateFilter()` call with a conditional that looks at the `Focused` property:

```
private void genericCheckbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Only update filter if the checkbox was triggered by the user
    if (((CheckBox)sender).Focused)
    {
        UpdateFilter();
    }
}

private void UpdateFilter()
{
    if (gdcSVNDefaultView.RowCount == 0)
        return;

    gdcSVNDefaultView.ActiveFilterString = BuildTableFilter();
    gdcSVNDefaultView.BestFitColumns();
}

private void gdcSVNDefaultView_ColumnFilterChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblTotalFileCount.Text = gdcSVNDefaultView.RowCount.ToString();

    if (gdcSVNDefaultView.ActiveFilterString.Contains("Normal"))
        cheNormalFiles.Checked = true;
    else
        cheNormalFiles.Checked = false;

    if (gdcSVNDefaultView.ActiveFilterString.Contains("bin") || 
        gdcSVNDefaultView.ActiveFilterString.Contains("obj"))
        cheBinObjFolders.Checked = true;
    else
        cheBinObjFolders.Checked = false;
}
```

Comment: Using `Focused` is by far the easiest approach if used carefully. Great find!