# Winform: How to know if CheckBox has been checked from code or UI

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I'm developing a winform c# application. In this application, I'm using Checkbox (JCS.ToggleSwitch to be precise).

I have added a `CheckedChanged` event to execute some code when the Checkbox has been checked.

I would like to be able to change the state of the checkbox in the code without triggering the code in this `CheckedChanged` event. In order to do that, I would like to know if it's possible to know if the checkbox state has been changed because of code or because the user clicked on the checkbox.

I tried to detect that with the sender `DummyCheckbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)`, although, the sender is the same when the state has been changed from a piece of code or by the UI.

Do you know if it's possible to only execute my code when the checkbox has been updated by the user?

```
 private JCS.ToggleSwitch DummyCheckbox;
 this.DummyCheckbox= new JCS.ToggleSwitch();
 this.DummyCheckbox.CheckedChanged += new JCS.ToggleSwitch.CheckedChangedDelegate(this.DummyCheckbox_CheckedChanged);

 private void DummyCheckbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      if(???) //CheckState has been changed from UI
      {
           if(DummyCheckbox.Checked)
           {
               //Code 1
           }
           else
           {
               //Code 2
           }
      }
      else //CheckState has been changed because of code "DummyCheckbox.Checked = true"
      {
           //Code 3
      }
 }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Differentiate between a user changing the Checkbox.Checked value, or it programmatically changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19500795/differentiate-between-a-user-changing-the-checkbox-checked-value-or-it-programm). You could use a flag, remove the handler and then add it back and or use some reflection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible in the way you are thinking of.
This is because changing the state will result in the UI element to fire the event.

What you could do, is to remove the even handler before you change the state, change it and add the event handler again. As such:

```
this.DummyCheckbox.CheckedChanged -= new JCS.ToggleSwitch.CheckedChangedDelegate(this.DummyCheckbox_CheckedChanged);
this.DummyCheckbox.Checked = true; //Or false if needed
this.DummyCheckbox.CheckedChanged += new JCS.ToggleSwitch.CheckedChangedDelegate(this.DummyCheckbox_CheckedChanged);
```